# JQuery is not recognized in Angular2 app

Tags: jquery, angular

In my Angular2 app, although, I have installed jQuery in my application, the $ is not recognized yet.

Here is my `Package.json`:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jQuery": "^1.7.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.22",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
```

Unfortunatly in line:

```
Observable.fromEvent($("#name"),"keyup")
```

It complains that

```
[ts] 
Cannot find name '$'.
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to write jquery import into your main html file.

Then you have to install typings for jquery:

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

And after that, declare `$` var in component file:

```
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
```

Then you can use it in component class:

```
export class FooComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log($);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this after installing jQuery using this command

> npm install jquery

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

Comment: doesn't work... the error is: **Cannot find JQueryStatic**;

Comment: do it after installing jquery

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in just 3 steps:

1 - Install jQuery definition - ***.d.ts** file:

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

2 - Add the script tag in your HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" />
```

3 - Now you can just use it. No need to declare any jQuery or $ variable because typings already did it for you. Period.

```
Observable.fromEvent($("#name"),"keyup");
```